# How to Deploy Standalone Blazor Webassembly

Tags: blazor-client-side

I am try to deploy a standalone blazor webassembly app to a IIS server hosted in Windows Server 2008.
Looking at the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0, I am supposed to copy from this directory "/bin/Release/{TARGET FRAMEWORK}/publish folder" into the static IIS website. 
I have also install URLRewrite.
But when I do that and try to open the site, I just get a "Loading..." message. 
Do I also need to install ASP.NET Core on the server?
What else may be causing this issue?

Thanks for any help.